# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc after pushing back into a vector

Tags: c++, exception, vector, bad-alloc

I'm facing a problem here, I've declared a pointer to a vector. After element insertion, it shows me this error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

Here is my code:

```
vector<string>* strategies;

cout << "Name of the player 1 : ";
cin >> name;

strategies->push_back(name);
```

Comment: Ask yourself, what `vector<int>` object does `strategies` point to?

Comment: `strategies->push_back(name);` is nonsense without a real vector behind that `strategies` pointer. There is none in this code. `strategies` is an indeterminate pointer. dereferencing it, including for member function execution, invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: after all i just realized I forgot to add new vector<string>(),I'm kinda new to C++,thanx anyway for your help

Answer (score 1):

I hope you'd have declared `string name;`

second, you are creating a pointer but not doing `new()` of some vector to which `*strategies` pointer really points. if all your purpose is to insert an element in vector then you really don't need a pointer rather you need object of `vector<string>` [code](https://godbolt.org/z/GhvzPcMEe)